# Search only in the product title on Amazon

Tags: search, amazon

I use Amazon a lot, but its search facilities are poor.

Today's example is that I'm looking for a 3TB internal disc drive.  Virtually every drive on the market gets a hit because 3TB is mentioned somewhere in the text or, worse still, in an advert on the page.

Can I restrict my search to the Product title only?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can search in product title only, but put into the search box "3TB internal disk drive" and search in department "computers"

When the search comes back, look on the left side of the screen and scroll down.  You should see a section to choose the size.  Click the box next to 3TB.